# Call pushViewController after presentViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, pushviewcontroller

Is it possible to somehow call `pushViewController` after `presentViewController` was called in Swift?

Or at least I need to implement the same behaviour when new `UIViewController` appears from the left side. The only option that I got to develop was to fake `pushViewController` with `CATransition()` but in this case the mechanism of new `UIViewController` appearance is different from the native.

- When you use native `pushViewController` new `UIViewController` appears over old one with fade.
- When you use faked `presentViewController` while new `UIViewController` appears previous just moves out of the screen.

I also tried to use `segue` but in this case new `UIViewController` appears from bottom.

So I prefer just to call `pushViewController` after `presentViewController` if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try using navigation controller and making segue on storyboard?

Comment: @Lu_ Yes, it also shows new `UIViewController` from bottom, but I need from the left side

Comment: so if you have segue in storyboard, simple performsegue method should do the job

Comment: [This](http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/) tutorial to custom transitions is great, might help you with this. Also you might want to describe better what you are trying to achieve in your question.

Comment: @Lu_ segue from the screen that was shown with `presentViewController` will show the next screen from the bottom, but I need from the left

Comment: @davidv The main idea is to show `UIViewController` with `pushViewController` when you on the `UIViewController` that is shown with `presentViewController`

Comment: @Danny, do you want to push to the second ViewController after presenting the first viewController ?

Answer (score 2):

You need use a `UINavigationController` and set it's `rootViewController` to the `UIViewController` you want to present (from the bottom - as a [modal](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uimodaltransitionstyle/uimodaltransitionstylecoververtical)).

Call `presentViewController` on that `UINavigationController`.

Then you can call [pushViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller) to push `UIViewControllers` onto the navigation stack and it will slide in from the side instead of the bottom.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I see here two things that do not fit with my model. Firstly `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical` is only IOS 9+ but I need this solution also for IOS 8, secondly at some moment I will net to set `rootViewController` back and I will get unwanted animation